# Lock/keep focus on input element?

Tags: qt, focus, qt5

I'm using a QLineEdit field within a touch-controlled environment, that's why my question is a bit strange. There is a situation where a user may have typed some illegal data into the QLineEdit input field and should not be allowed to leave this input field until the illegal input has been corrected.

Now when I check the focus-lost-event for the QLineEdit, it is too late. This event is sent when e.g. an other button is clicked but this button is already processed at this point, and the probably wrong data in my input field are used.

So how can I solve this? Is there a possibility to lock the focus on an element so that all other widgets can't be used until this lock is released (disabling all the other widgets is NOT a solution)?

Or is there some kind of pre-focus-event where I can inhibit the event to the other widget and keep my input field active and focused exclusively?

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do, when user clicks outside your application? So focus will be lost globally.

Comment: SaZ: this possibility does not exit, user has only this window and can't go to a desktop/an other application

Comment: It doesn't exists in your case. But it exists in logic of Qt.

Comment: Any comments to my answer? Is it clear?

Comment: SaZ: yes it is clear but not really a solution since it looks really strange when all other widgets are disabled just because one is currently edited...

Comment: It is ok, because there are no other legal ways to keep focus. If you will use statemachines for all GUI - it will be simple. But... as you wish, you may look for other solution a lot of time, or use correct one.

Comment: Focus shouldn't be managed by user code. It is good practice to use validators insead of other crazy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is complex, but you should think about it...

I propose you to create a [state machine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) that will handle enabled/disabled properties of all your GUI elements. When edit field gets a focus you should disable all other widgets, that may accept input. On text change event you should valiate data and if it became correct - then restore enabled property.

Some pseudo-code:

```
enum States { LockedState, NormalState };

class Validator
{
  signals:
    void valid();
    void invalid();
  slots:
    void onTextChanged( QString text );
};

class Gui
{
public:
  void initStateMachine();

  Validator *_validator;
}

void Gui::initStateMachine()
{
_validator = new Validator();

QVector< QState * > _states;
_states.push_back( new QState() );
_states.push_back( new QState() );

// States
_states[LockedState]->assignProperty( ui->okbutton, "enabled", false );
_states[LockedState]->assignProperty( ui->cancelbutton, "enabled", false );
_states[LockedState]->assignProperty( ui->custombutton, "enabled", false );

_states[NormalState]->assignProperty( ui->okbutton, "enabled", true );
_states[NormalState]->assignProperty( ui->cancelbutton, "enabled", true );
_states[NormalState]->assignProperty( ui->custombutton, "enabled", true );

// Transitions
_states[LockedState]->addTransition( _validator, SIGNAL( valid() ), _states[NormalState] );

_states[NormalState]->addTransition( _validator, SIGNAL( invalid() ), _states[LockedState] );

// Go
for ( auto s : _states )
    _stateMachine->addState( s );
_stateMachine->setInitialState( _states[NormalState] );
_stateMachine->setRunning( true );

connect( ui->textEdit, &textChanged, _validator, &onTextChanged );
}
```

Feel free to ask, if you need details.